# Angular select box default to existing value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an angular user edit page with a select box:

```
    <select name="clientRole" ng-model="client.role" required>
        <option value="{{client.role}}">{{client.role}}</option>
        <option ng-repeat="role in roleOptions" value="{{role.name}}">{{role.name}}
    </select>
```

The array "roleOptions" contains all of the possible roles.
This page is used to edit a client, and the client will have a role already assigned.
When the page comes up, I want the role that is assigned to the client to show as the default value.
The way I have it above, the role is duplicated.

Does angular have a way that handles this, or do I need to edit the "roleOptions" array to delete the client role before the page is called?

Comment: Use [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) alongside your select element instead of `ng-repeat` with the option element. That way your `ng-model` will implicitly select the default value.

Comment: @miqid Why don't you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) instead:

```
<select name="clientRole" 
        ng-model="client.role" 
        ng-options="role.id as role.name for role in roleOptions" 
        required>     
</select>
```

In this example, I assume that `client.role` is your `role.id`